# Defining multiple ARNs which can trigger a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Here's the sample CloudFormation syntax I am seeing in the AWS documentations for `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping`:

```
Type: "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping"
Properties: 
  BatchSize: Integer
  Enabled: Boolean
  EventSourceArn: String
  FunctionName: String
  StartingPosition: String
```

Say I have a set of DDB Stream ARNs which I want to use as trigger of one lambda function (instead of one ARN as trigger). I tried to define this relationship like this:

```
Parameters:
   DDBStreamARN:
     Type: String
     Default: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId1
     AllowedValues:
       - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId1
       - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId2
       - ...
     Description: ARNs for the DDB Streams

Resources:
  RegistrationRequestStreamMapping:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
     Properties:
       BatchSize: 70
       EventSourceArn:
         Ref: DDBStreamARN
       FunctionName:
         Fn::GetAtt:
           - TestLambdaFunction
           - Arn
       StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
       Enabled: True
```

But the syntax doesn't seem to work since only the default value (`arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId1`) is working as trigger and the other ARNs wont trigger the lambda function. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define many AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping for same lambda.

For example;

```
RegistrationRequestStreamMapping1:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
     Properties:
       BatchSize: 70
       EventSourceArn:
         Ref: DDBStream1ARN
       FunctionName:
         Fn::GetAtt:
           - TestLambdaFunction
           - Arn
       StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
       Enabled: True

RegistrationRequestStreamMapping2:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
     Properties:
       BatchSize: 70
       EventSourceArn:
         Ref: DDBStream2ARN
       FunctionName:
         Fn::GetAtt:
           - TestLambdaFunction
           - Arn
       StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
       Enabled: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Deploy your CFT twice. Once with `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId1` and second time with `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:someId2` as the value of `DDBStreamARN` parameter.